# Can Gerrit be treated as Git?

Tags: git, gerrit

My team at work uses Perforce.
Another team that we need to cooperate with used to use Git. Now they have moved to Gerrit.

I used to think Gerrit is a code review tool much us Crucible (only that it blocks unreviewed changes), but now I keep hearing that it substitutes Git and not adds to it.

Should we be worried? Do all the git-oriented tools and plugins work with Gerrit as well, or is the workflow and interface completely different?

A little crazy example: is it possible to do a Crucible review on a Gerrit repo, or show the code in Fisheye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerrit provides its own git storage for repos rather than attaches to existing ones. This is probably needed for some internal review branch handling.

Everything else is same as git, you can work with any git-oriented tools with gerrit-managed repositories. Access to repos is through SSH keys, nothing is any different.

Adding another review tool on top of gerrit-managed repos is possible, but is indeed crazy :). There is a problem attaching gerrit on top of other repos (e.g. GitHub), however there are open-sources forks and plugins for such stuff as well.

Comment: I know, I know :) I wanted to exaggerate a bit. One of the tools I am really interested in, at least at this early stage, is P4 Git Fusion.